# Display date Mon-Sun for certain start and end timeframe with results in sql

Tags: sql, date, db2

I'm not really sure how to explain how I want this done, but I am working with a DB2 database and I am looking to display certain fields accumulated by week from Mon-Sun.  To give you an example, I will give an example below:

--------Date-------------------Participants---------Logins----

1/6/2014 - 1/12/2014             3402                  8302

1/13/2014 - 1/19/2014           1052                  3485

1/13/2014 - 1/19/2014           2316                  5612

1/20/2014 - 1/26/2014            865                   1925

1/27/2014 - 2/2/2014             1674                  2648

This is an example of what I am looking to do.  So in essence, from Monday the 6th to Sunday the 12th, their was a sum of 3402 participants who were present on a Web site and these participants have a log in total of 8302.  I want this to be weekly and displayed for however many weeks that I need it for.  Currently, I am looking to do weekly for the beginning of 2012 to the end of 2013.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Update

**Query:**

```
SELECT WEEK_ISO(LOGIN_DATETIME) AS WEEK, YEAR(LOGIN_DATETIME) AS YEAR, 
       COUNT (CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='rollover' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS ROLLOVER,
           COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='rollover' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS DISTINCT_ROLLOVER,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='rollin' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS ROLLIN,
       COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='rollin' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS DISTINCT_ROLLIN,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='inccont' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS INCCONT,
       COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='inccont' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS DISTINCT_INCCONT,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='catchup' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS CATCHUP,
       COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN OFFER_CODE='catchup' THEN "SSN" ELSE NULL END) AS DISTINCT_CATCHUP
  FROM GPTM.WEB_HISTORY_TRACKING, GPTM.WEB_DISPLAY_CONFIG
  WHERE GPTM.WEB_HISTORY_TRACKING.WEB_DISPLAY_ID=GPTM.WEB_DISPLAY_CONFIG.WEB_DISPLAY_ID
  AND MESSAGE_TYPE <> 'SURVEY' 
  AND LOGIN_DATETIME BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
  GROUP BY WEEK_ISO(LOGIN_DATETIME), YEAR(LOGIN_DATETIME)
ORDER BY YEAR asc
WITH UR;
```

**Results:**

```
WEEK    YEAR    ROLLOVER    DISTINCT_ROLLOVER   ROLLIN  DISTINCT_ROLLIN     INCCONT DISTINCT_INCCONT    CATCHUP DISTINCT_CATCHUP
----    ----    --------    -----------------   ------  ---------------     ------- ----------------    ------- ----------------
 1      2012        1               1              0           0               0           0               0           0
 4      2012        0               0              0           0               1           1               0           0
 5      2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 6      2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 7      2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 8      2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 9      2012        1               1              0           0               0           0               0           0
 12     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 13     2012        1               1              0           0               0           0               0           0
 15     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 17     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 18     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 19     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 20     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
 21     2012        1               1              0           0               0           0               0           0
 23     2012        0               0              0           0               0           0               0           0
```

I have the weeks set up from Mon-Sun bu was wondering if it was possible to do it in a range date form like I have in the example above.

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: you need to generate the dates first. Then you can use the dateadd function to calculate what you want.

Comment: Can we get some sample starting data (this helps to verify our efforts troubleshooting your problems)?  Don't worry about full counts - just dummy up something small/anonymous, and change your result table to match.  Also, what have you tried so far in terms of queries?  What kind of week - strict Monday->Sunday, ISO week number, starting on Jan 1st...?  A `Calendar` table will be useful here (for optimization at minimum, or required depending on the definition of "week"), so look into creating it if you don't have one yet.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I will update to show you the query and some results

Comment: ... I asked for _source_ data for the given results, and this appears to need an extra step (note: do **not** show source data with SSNs in it, unless you have made/used dummy ones - you shouldn't be testing/viewing real ones anyways).  If you have a calendar file with ISO week, this is trivial, and will use indicies (although your current version will be truncating starting/ending weeks due to how the value is calculated.  [Don't use BETWEEN with timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)